# Method not found: CryptProtectData

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0

Dears all
I am working on a project using Identity authentication. Everything was working alright and I added automapper library. After that when i ran the project i started getting;

> MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.UnsafeNativeMethods.CryptProtectData(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*,
> IntPtr, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB*, IntPtr, IntPtr,
> UInt32, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.DATA_BLOB ByRef)'.

I am unable to trace the source of this error. Any help will be appreciated.

I am building the application on .net core 6.